# How do I install PSCX Powershell module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm running Windows 7 with PowerShell 2 installed.

I've downloaded version 2.1 from here - http://pscx.codeplex.com/releases

The Release notes say

- unblock the zip file - {which I did}
- extract the contents of the ZIP file to your $env:Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules folder

I was unsure what $env:Home was so a bit of searching determined that the release notes are expecting an environment variable called Home which doesn't exist on my machine.

A bit more searching says use what is defined as `~` on my machine. So in a PS prompt I run `cd ~`

Which on my machine led to a network drive `U:`

I created the following directories `U:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and copied the extracted Pscx-2.1.0 to the Modules folder. Opened a PowerShell prompt and typed `Get-Module -ListAvailable`. This didn't give me Pscx in the results.

The above steps actually gave me this folder tree `U:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx-2.1.0\Pscx-2.1.0`

So I copied the files up a level and tried again with `U:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx-2.1.0\` and also tried with `U:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx\`

I also tried all of the above with this path `U:\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx-2.1.0\`

I'm guessing that the Modules aren't actually supposed to be in this directory, so a bit more searching leads to this command. `(Get-ChildItem Env:\PSModulePath).Value`

which gives the following result

`C:\Users\my.name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`

So I copy the Pscx-2.1.0 folder to here `C:\Users\my.name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx-2.1.0`

And still no luck.

What step am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hadn't actually completed the last step of my above question completely which turned out to be the answer.

Here is that answer for completeness

- Unblock the zip file you have downloaded
- extract the zip file - this will likely give a folder structure of `Pscx-2.1.0/Pscx-2.1.0/{lots of files}`
- rename the child folder to Pscx - ie - `Pscx-2.1.0/Pscx/{lots of files}`
- In Powershell prompt run `(Get-ChildItem Env:\PSModulePath).Value` and note the modules folder location.
- Copy the **child** `Pscx folder` to the Modules folder location given above.
- In Powershell prompt run Get-Module -ListAvailable to see the Pscx module available.

Comment: Just Add pscx folder in Modules folder. and things works fine.

Comment: The other answer - using `find-package` is much simpler.

Answer (score 9):

In **PowerShell 5.0**, you can do:

```
Find-Package pscx | ? ProviderName -eq PSModule | Install-Package -Force
```

The `-Force` parameter will cause it to upgrade if an older version is already installed.

In **PowerShell 5.1**, you'll need:

```
Find-Package pscx | ? ProviderName -eq PowerShellGet | Install-Package -Force
```

or

```
Find-Package pscx -ProviderName PowerShellGet | Install-Package -Force
```

or just

```
Install-Package pscx -Force
```

Comment: This has no effect for me, it just runs silently. It was installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell CommunityExtensions\Pscx3\Pscx` but I can't really use it.

Comment: In PowerShell 5.1 you'll need Find-Package pscx | ? ProviderName -eq PowerShellGet | Install-Package -Force or  Find-Package pscx -ProviderName PowerShellGet | Install-Package -Force instead

Answer (score 4):

Just run

```
choco install pscx
```

See [chocolatey.org](http://chocolatey.org) for a one-liner to get the `choco` command.

Keep in mind you may still have to call this in your scripts before running their commands:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser #allows scripts to run from the interwebs, such as pcsx
```

Comment: This does not work anymore because pscx is unlisted and hidden from package listing. See https://chocolatey.org/packages/pscx for details.

Answer (score 2):

> **Update**: Looks like PsGet is no longer maintained, but source is still available on github.

You can also use [**PsGet**](https://github.com/psget/psget) to easily search and install PowerShell modules.

You can check which modules have been added to PsGet by browsing for all modules:

```
> Get-PsGetModuleInfo *
```

Or locate this one specfically:

```
> Get-PsGetModuleInfo pscx
```

Then you can install based on that information:

```
> Install-Module pscx
```

Comment: Strangely this worket but installing from `choco` did not.

Answer (score 0):

After spending lot of time searching here and there, i found this blog has very clear steps to solve. try it may helps u ..

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/18/install-the-pscx-and-80-new-cmdlets-to-ease-powershell-use.aspx

Comment: This answer is completely dependent on an external link. Should that link ever become invalid, the answer would become useless. So please edit your post and add at least a summary of the proposed solution. Thank you!